# Meaning of 'under strict embargo'

Tags: meaning

In a press release draft, I came across the phrase 'under strict embargo'.

Here is the complete text:

"UNDER STRICT EMBARGO UNTIL MAY 17, 2015"

What does the phrase mean in the given context?

Comment: An embargo is usually any regulation or policy that restricts trade, ban the publication of (documents), as for security or copyright reasons.

Comment: Well, you didn't give us the context.  What's under embargo, a document, a product, a foodstuff?

Answer (score 4):

**Must be kept strictly under wraps until ...** (ie 'Must not be released before ...').

From [The Creative Frontier](http://thecreativefrontier.blogspot.co.uk/):

> I've pulled together some of my top tips for writing press releases,
>   and would love to hear if you've got any more!
>
> 1. Make the timing clear – when you send out a press release you have to let the recipients know when they are allowed to share the
>      information. If you're sending out a press release that has to stay
>      under wraps until a certain date it means it's 'under embargo'. Make
>      this clear by stating *Under strict embargo until DATE and TIME* at the
>      top of your press release .doc and your email. If your press release
>      can be shared immediately put *Immediate release: DATE YOU SEND PRESS*
>      *RELEASE OUT*....